# React-native login with API refresh HomeScreen after login with another user

Tags: react-native

After I log out with a user and then log in with another, the data of the last user persists in the main screen, I need for that Main screen to refresh after another user logs-in.

How is it possible to do that?

this is in my `componentDidMount()`

```
async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
            'AbhayaLibre-Regular': require('../assets/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Regular.ttf'),
            'AbhayaLibre-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Bold.ttf'),
        });
        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
            this.authCheck()
            if (this.state.loggedIn == "false") {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
            } else {
                this.authUser();
                this.fetchSubjects();
            }
    }
```

It puzzles me because I'm not sure how to run that code again AFTER a new user logs-in after another logged out.

Code snipped of the login:

```
<Button icon="send" mode="contained" text="#1ebc61" color="white" onPress={() => {
    axios.post('http://homewrk.test/api/auth/login', {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    }).then(res => {
        this.setState({ token: res.data.access_token });
        this.storeKey();
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }).catch(() => {
        this.setState({ error: true })
    })
}}>
```

`authCheck()`

```
async authCheck() {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
        const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
        console.log(access);
        axios.get(`http://homewrk.test/api/check`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': access,
            }
        }).then(res => {
            const isLoggedIn = res.data;
            this.setState({ loggedIn: isLoggedIn });
        })
    }
```

storing the key:

```
storeKey = async () => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('access', this.state.token);
            console.log("done");
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add code snippet of login

Comment: Just added it in the post

Comment: Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: Yes, I am using react-navigation

Comment: react-navigation version 4?

Comment: yes, react-navigation ^4.3.7

Comment: any idea @Rajan ?

Comment: @DanielLogvin could you share your ```authCheck``` & ```storeKey``` functions

Comment: @SDushan done, check em out

Answer (score 0):

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'AbhayaLibre-Regular': require('../assets/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Regular.ttf'),
        'AbhayaLibre-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener("willFocus", () => {
        this.authCheck()
        if (this.state.loggedIn == "false") {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
        } else {
            this.authUser();
            this.fetchSubjects();
        }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.focusListener.remove();
}
```

Comment: My app crashes after trying this

Comment: Sadly, I'm not getting any error, the app just crashes

Comment: Can you attached the debugger and see what is the error you are getting?